# Обработка форм в Django 2.0 (ошибка 403, csrf)

Tags: django, csrf

Подскажите, как в Django 2.0 использовать CSRF? Раньше можно было делать

```
form = {}
form.update(csrf(request))
if request.POST:
    form['name'] = request.POST.get['name']
// и дальше как то обрабатывать
```

и в конце

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Теперь во второй версии это не работает(ругается на form.update и RequestContext). Как теперь обрабатывать формы?

P.S. Форма используется своя.

Comment: Обожемой! Во-первых, render_to_response и RequestContext уже года 3 как не используются. Почитали бы вы какую-нибудь актуальную документацию. Во-вторых, я даже не знал, что есть такой способ работать с csrf. Такой через задницу. Почему бы просто не вставить csrf-токен в форму?

Comment: csrf_token уже есть в форме. Уже нашел, что через render теперь отправляется. Но как теперь получить данные из формы?
P.S. И да, последний раз пользовался Django около 3 лет назад)

Comment: Так же, как три года назад: `form = SomeForm(request.POST); if form.is_valid(): name = form.cleaned_data['name']`

Comment: Но в этом случае, как я понимаю, используется встроенная форма Django, которая описывается в forms.py, а мне нужно обрабатывать свою форму с другими стилями

Comment: Или стили для встроенной формы тоже можно указать свои?

Comment: Можно указать свои. Даже более, чем одним способом можно этого добиться.

Comment: Ладно, попробую реализовать встроенной формой. Спасибо за советы